# Why won't my Rails server run? I get an error that a file is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error that I get is

> /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in
>   `read': No such file or directory -
>   /Users/me/ready96/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)

This is weird because I have the exact same codebase in a different directory and it works fine.

Comment: what is at line 115 of your `configuration.rb` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `database.yml` in `config` folder.